# Nvidia Graphics shows as unknown

Tags: nvidia

I install the Nnvidia 313 drivers. Everything works fine but the graphic driver is listed as unknown. In the Nvidia app, Nvidia server settings it's says the correct version.. the desktop seems to be running in 3D, not sure how to verify that but the experience is set to "standard"

What should I do here for Ubuntu to list the correct driver?

Comment: Only when I had 11.10 my graphics info was shown, but not in 12.04 or 12.10. I think this makes no problem, however it shows some incompatibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the system will solve this issue. I would recommend activating the **Proposed** repositories in case you have not yet done so, but after upgrading 12.10 that minor bug should be fixed. Is not an error, nor does it mean you are not using the drivers correctly.

The bug is simply that the Window, in that line stops mentioning the correct video card. This does not affect the performance, 3D effects or anything else graphics related if that is what is making you doubt.

Here is 12.10 after upgrading and using the 313 drivers as you are doing right now:

[image]

And this one

[image]

Also in the **Software Sources** I have all updates active:

[image]

So with that in mind, do an update and done. Even if you still see that text not showing the video card, it is just that, a text that is not showing the video card. The video card will still work fine (I know it scares me when I did not see it detected there the first time).

UPDATE - Just did an awesome check with Synaptic and Aptitude to find what did I do apart from the mentioned stuff above. The only thing I found that involved video cards was installing the mesa utils because I normally tend to use the glx commands to check stuff out and to run the `sudo nvidia-xconfig` command to create the `xorg.conf` file only if I got an Nvidia missing configuration file bug. Maybe you can give it a go:

`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

and restart the session or reboot. Apart from this, we would end with the same configuration for everything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did select that option and ran al the updates, rebooted but it is still shown as unknown. You are right about the performance, it does work as it should, only in the details the driver is wrong. Anything else i can try?

Comment: @AdrianSultu Updated answer after checking all packages related to video cards. Let me know if something happens.

Comment: You're awesome! i did sudo apt-get install mesa-utils, rebooted and did sudo nvidia-xconfig and now the correct video card shows! Thank you so much!