# 12.04 nvidia graphics resolution problem

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, resolution

I am trying to use OpenGL on my laptop, a Dell Inspiron n5110 with Nvidia GeForce GT 525M.
I managed to install my graphics card by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
sudo reboot
```

But then I had some errors at my OpenGL program and since then I entered a lot of commands and managed to do something and now my resolution is fixed at 640X480.
These are the commands I entered to fix my OpenGL problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-   mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

And after running these commands I noticed that even though my graphics card was properly installed, in System settings->Details it did not appear. So I read this [Nvidia Graphics shown as unknown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254348/nvidia-graphics-shows-as-unknown) and entered the following commands and that's when my resolution got stuck at 640X480

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
sudo reboot
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

So I guess that what I am trying to ask is how can I revert my laptop to it's previous state

Also here is the output of the `lspci | grep VGA` command:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first to disable the ppa and then install nvidia-current from ubuntu archives:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

Comment: Nothing has changed. The driver was installed before running the commands you told me about. I thought that the `mesa-utils` package was the problem so before you answered I uninstalled it from the Synaptic Package Manager